# Cloudant Geospatial query

Tags: geospatial, cloudant

I'm new to cloudant, i want to fetch records by lat and long with particular category.

//This is getting records by Lat and Long

```
dbname/_design/ad/_geo/geoidx?lat=29.2609417&lon=71.1750101&radius=100
```

but i want to fetch records by particular category something like this...

dbname/_design/ad/_geo/geoidx?lat=22.2609417&lon=73.1750101&radius=100&**item_type_id: '12345'**

how can i achieve this? please reply... 
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this using the Cloudant Geo index. You need to use Cloudant Search (powered by Lucene Geo), which allows you to combine a radius search with attribute search. Here's a tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/01/07/geospatial-query-with-cloudant-search/

The only caveat is with Cloudant Search you can only do bounding box and radius searches -- no polygon searches.